# Best way to create .XSL file using VB.Net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

Every month we receive a .csv with two columns of data. First Column is a Code and then other one is a description. ex: M23 | Missing invoice.

I need to use this data to create a new .XSL file that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="AdjustmentRemarkCodeReplacements">
        <xsl:param name="CodeValue"/><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$CodeValue = 'A0'">Patient refund amount.</xsl:when><xsl:when test="$CodeValue = 'A1'">Claim denied charges.</xsl:when><xsl:when test="$CodeValue = '999'">TESTING ONE TWO THREE now.</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise/></xsl:choose></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="RemarkCodeReplacements">
        <xsl:param name="CodeValue"/><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$CodeValue = 'M1'">X-ray not taken within the past 12 months or near enough to the start of treatment.</xsl:when><xsl:when test="$CodeValue = 'M2'">Not paid separately when the patient is an inpatient.</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise/></xsl:choose></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

An XSL is normally used to parse, or transform, an XML file into something else (XML or another format).

Do you really want to create an XSL file from the CSV file?  For example, if you will you be using the output from the XSL you create to then transform some other XML file not mentioned.

If so, then you won't be using any XML coding to convert the csv to XSL.  You will use a StreamWriter or something similar to write a xsl:template for each line in your csv and replace the CodeValue and description with the values from the csv file.

Sorry, this should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep... more of a reader at StackOverflow than a asker/answerer.

**If this is still an issue for you**, please add a comment to this post or your original comment with an explanation and I will see what else I can do.  Otherwise, **if this post helped you**, an upvote or Mark as Answer would be appreciated.